# How do I avoid getting data printed to stdout in my return value?

Tags: powershell, return-value, stdout

In doing some Powershell automation, I'm having trouble with the way that data written to stdout by a `.cmd` file is automatically captured. I have two functions that do something like the following:

```
function a {
    & external.cmd # prints "foo"
    return "bar"
}

function b {
    $val = a
    echo $val # prints "foobar", rather than just "bar"
}
```

Basically, data that `external.cmd` sends to stdout is added to the return value of `a`, even though all I really want to return from `a` is the string that I specified. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here are a few different approaches for handling this:

- capture the output of the `.cmd` script:

  ```
    $output = & external.cmd # saves foo to $output so it isn't returned from the function
  ```
- redirect the output to null (throw it away)

  ```
    & external.cmd | Out-Null # throws stdout away
  ```
- redirect it to a file

  ```
    & external.cmd | Out-File filename.txt
  ```
- ignore it in the caller by skipping it in the array of objects that's returned from the function

  ```
    $val = a
    echo $val[1] #prints second object returned from function a (foo is object 1... $val[0])
  ```

In PowerShell, **any** output value your code does not capture, is returning the "caller" object (including *stdout, stderr*, etc).  So you have to capture or pipe it to something that doesn't return a value, or you'll end up with the `object[]` itself as your return value from the function.

The `return` keyword is really just for clarity, with the exact same effect as just writing the variable alone (as shown), but with an immediate exit of a script block in PowerShell.  Something like this would even work (not verbatim but just to give you the idea):

```
function foo()
{
    "a"
    "b"
    "c"
}

PS> $bar = foo
PS> $bar.gettype()
System.Object[]
PS> $bar
a
b
c

function foobar()
{
    "a"
    return "b"
    "c"
}

PS> $myVar = foobar
PS> $myVar
a
b
```

Comment: I have also seen people do things like: `& { & "app.exe" } | Out-Default`, but this need more explanation.

Comment: Thanks @not2qubit `& { & "app.exe" } | Out-Default` works for me

Answer (score 19):

I generally prefer to use one of the following two techniques which, in my opinion, make the code more readable:

- Cast an expression to void in order to suppress the return value:

  `[void] (expression)`
- Assign the output value to the $null variable:

  `$null = expression`

For example:

```
function foo
{
    # do some work
    return "success"
}

function bar
{
    [void] (foo)  # no output
    $null = foo   # no output
    return "bar"
}

bar # outputs bar
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want the output from the command to still print to the powershell command line, you can do a variant of the accepted answer:

```
& external.cmd | Out-Host
```