# Start process, wait for it, and throw away all output

Tags: powershell

I'd like to do this in PowerShell:

```
myprogram.exe arg1 arg2 >nul 2>nul
```

How does it work? There are like a million options to start processes in PowerShell, it's impossible to know the right one you need at a time.

Comment: this didn't helped? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660966/how-do-i-avoid-getting-data-printed-to-stdout-in-my-return-value

Comment: Start-Process -FilePath "myprogram.exe" -ArgumentList arg1 arg2 -Wait
^^ This will make it waiting. But I dont know what you mean with "throw away all output"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nul` is a special device (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/613335) on SuperUser for instance) that's available in CMD, but not in PowerShell. In PowerShell you can use `$null` instead. Starting with PowerShell v3 you can use `*>` to redirect all [output streams](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/), but since you want to redirect output from an external program there should only be output on STDOUT and STDERR (Success and Error output stream in PowerShell terms), so `>$null 2>$null` should be fine.

A notable difference between CMD and PowerShell is that PowerShell doesn't include the current working directory in the PATH (the list of directories that is searched when you call a program/script without a path). If you want to run `myprogram.exe` from the current directory you need to prepend it with the path to the current directory (`./`).

You may also want to use the [call operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) (`&`). Although it's not required in this particular case I consider using it good practice. If you specify the command as a string (for instance because the path or filename contains spaces, or you want to use a variable instead of a literal) you MUST use the call operator, otherwise the statement would throw an error.

Something like this

```
& ./myprogram.exe arg1 arg2 >$null 2>$null
```

or like this

```
& ./myprogram.exe arg1 arg2 *>$null
```

should work.

Comment: I didn't know that `>` works in PowerShell, too. I've only seen things like `| Out-Null` which partially don't work with all the different methods like `Start-Process`, `Invoke-Expression` etc.

Comment: `| Out-Null` basically does the same as `>$null`. It doesn't suppress error output. If you want to suppress error output by piping into `Out-Null` you need to merge the Error output stream into the Success output stream (`2>&1`) before piping the combined stream into `Out-Null`.